# How to make Http Request and Parse the data to a model class in Flutter

Tags: http, flutter

***I am having a endpoint:*** [***https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22***](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22)

**It gives a Json Response called:**

```
{"coord":{"lon":139.01,"lat":35.02},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":285.514,"pressure":1013.75,"humidity":100,"temp_min":285.514,"temp_max":285.514,"sea_level":1023.22,"grnd_level":1013.75},"wind":{"speed":5.52,"deg":311},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1485792967,"sys":{"message":0.0025,"country":"JP","sunrise":1485726240,"sunset":1485763863},"id":1907296,"name":"Tawarano","cod":200}
```

---

Here i am using the Http library given in [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

**LoadingScreen.dart**

```
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    // TODO: implement deactivate
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //Get the current location
            getLocation();
          },
          child: Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future getLocation() async {
    Location mLoc = Location();
    await mLoc.getLocation();
    print("Co-ordinates fetched");
    print("< -------------------------------------------------- >");
    getData(latitude: mLoc.currentLatitude, longitude: mLoc.currentLongitude);
  }

  void getData({String longitude, String latitude}) async {
    Response response = await get(
        "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

---

**What I am able to do:**

I am able to get the data from server successfully and print the json Response in log.

**What I am trying to to:**

1. In android I parse the data using library called `GSON` into a model
   class.
2. How to achieve the same in Flutter ( Looking for a solution that offers similar capability like `GSON`)

Answer (score 0):

This sample includes a sample how you can fetch a JSON value from the network.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Location {
  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getWeather() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
}

void main() async {
  print((await Location.getWeather())["main"]["temp"]);
}
```

It will print

> 285.514

Comment: `["main"]["temp"]` I have to mention the keys manually to check the levels ... but `Gson-In android` does this for you and give the response in a model class .... are there any libraries in flutter that does the same

Answer (score 0):

Since Reflection isn't support in Dart. You cannot just give a class and request the JSON string to be deserialised. You can use [Json Serializeble](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) to keep you model class in sync with you JSON. If you need `Retrofit` like automatice serialisation you can look into [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) which supports this with the help of transformer